# Firestore delete an index inside an array

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i am trying to delete an index inside array

this is the data structure 
[image]

I want the user to delete the selected car so it could be index 0 or whatever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion is fetch the document and delete the item at which index you want from the local array and update the remote document. Or you can use `.document('docID').updateData('cars': FieldValue.arrayRemove([{the-item-map}]));`. Maybe there are other options but these two options are acceptable, I prefer to use first one.

Comment: Thanks i never thought to do it . The first method sounds good